# Entity listener on a @MappedSuperclass does not work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, mappedsuperclass, entitylisteners, table-per-class

### Background

I am using EclipseLink (version 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461, implementation provider for the JPA 2.0 specification).

Consider this `@MappedSuperclass`, called **Person**:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({Listener.class})
public abstract class Person implements Serializable
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

He is *abstract* and has a listener (**Listener**) attached to him. Here is the listener implementation:

```
public class Listener
{
    @PrePersist
    public void sayHi(Person person) {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
}
```

Then we have an **Employee** class that extends **Person**:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Employee extends Person
{
    private int salary;
}
```

**Employee** is still *abstract* and not meant to be instantiated. However, Employee is thought of as possibly being part of a relationship and thus annotated `@Entity`. The hierarchy continues with a *non-abstract entity* called **PartTimeEmployee**:

```
@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee
{
    private int hoursWorked;
}
```

**PartTimeEmployee** is meant to be instantiated. Let's try that and see what happens! All seem to work fine except one minor detail. The entity listener registered on `@MappedSuperclass` **Person** is not called. The listener is not even called if we move up the `@EntityListeners` annotation from **Person** to **Employee**.

### One fix

Move the `@EntityListeners` annotation all the way to **PartTimeEmployee** and he shall be called. Hmm.

### Another fix

We can keep the listener registered on **Person** and the listener will be called like intended, *if we completely leave out* the `@Inheritance` annotation on **Employee**. But then of course, I get a single table strategy which I don't want to have. Likewise we can be a little bit more explicit and change the strategy value from `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` to `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` and the listener will be called. Only problem of course is that my database schema will not look the way I want it to.

So, the core of the problem here is the `@Inheritance` annotation (more specifically; changing strategy to one table per class) on the **Employee** class, which makes EclipseLink forget all about entity listeners in the hierarchy.

That is not at all what I had expected. What is it that I do not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have found an EclipseLink bug, they're common with inheritance annotations.

I suggest upgrading to latest version of EclipseLink, your version is over a year old.  If that doesn't work then you'll have to annotate your derived classes with your listener.

If you're feeling particularly adventurous you can implement a SessionCustomizer which will add listeners to classes at start-up.

Comment: I tried with EclipseLink version 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345 and the problem is still there. When I went to file a bug report I found that a bug has been reported that seems to be describing the very same issue I am having:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=302194